# Like-Unlike function in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I would like to implement this like and unlike into codeigniter. I can do it in the normal php using the following codes but I just don't why it is not working in codeigniter below is my database table and my model view and controller. any help would be appritiated. thanks.

**posts table**

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**like-unlike table**

```
CREATE TABLE `like-unlike` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `purpose` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Jquery file**

```
function likeItem(post_id)
{
    if ($("#likeItem_" + post_id).text() == "Like")
    {
        $("#likeItem_" + postid).html('Unlike');
        var purpose = "Like";
    } else
    {
        $("#likeItem_" + post_id).html('Like');
        var purpose = "UnLike";
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url('posts/likes');?>",
        data: "postId=" + postId + "&purpose=" + purpose,
        success: function (data)
        {
            // do seomthing here with data
            // console.log(data) --> to see data return or not
        }
    }
    );
```

**This is my model "Post_model.php"**

```
public function itemLike() {
    $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $postId = $this->input->post('post_id');
    $purpose = $this->input->post('purpose');
    if ($purpose == "Like") {
        // echo 'test';
        // exit();
        $data = array(
            "user_id" => $id,
            "post_id" => $postId,
        );
        $this->db->insert('like', $data);
    } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
}
```

This is my view file

```
<li><a class="like-unlike" href="#" id="likeItem_{$item['post_id']}" onclick="likeItem({$item['post_id']})">Like</a></li>
```

**This is my Controller "Post.php"**

```
public function likeItem()
{
    $this->usermodel->itemLike();
}
```

Comment: did you check the logs ?

Comment: and when is UnLike?

Comment: You're trying to post to `like-unlike` while your db is called: `like_unlike`

Comment: you lost `purpose` int(2) NOT NULL, in array before insert

Comment: my chrome  crashed so I am using safari and I could not

Comment: "You're trying to post to like-unlike while your db is called: like_unlike" was a typographical error

Comment: You're logs are on the server and has nothing to do with your browser.

Comment: _"was a typographical error"_ - Did you rewrite the code here on SO? Please don't do that. Copy/paste the _real_ code instead of letting us spend time going through a rewrite that might contain other/more issues (like the one I pointed out).

Comment: I have . I am trying to get user_id with session so that a user can only like once. but when I click the like button nothing happens on screen or database

Comment: @King have your this problem is solved or not??

Answer (score 1):

In your database schema, you have mentioned table `like_unlike` and you are saving data in to table `like-unlike`.
Also, you set column `purpose` for mandatory and you are not passing any values here:

```
$data = array(
"user_id" => $id,
"post_id" => $postId,
);
```

You don't need to pass data if you use default value. You also need to keep in mind that column `purpose` holds only integer value as per your database schema.
Apart from this you also need to modify code mention by @JYoThI

Comment: I am confused please break this down.

Comment: I have . I am trying to get user_id with session so that a user can only like once. but when I click the like button nothing happens on screen or database

Answer (score 0):

**1st :** Post `name` mismatch `data : "postId=" + post_id + "&purpose=" + purpose,`

```
$postId = $this->input->post('post_id');
```

change to

```
$postId = $this->input->post('postId');
```

**2nd :** pass the data like below  and variable name is `post_id` not  `postId`

```
data : {postId:postid,purpose:purpose},
```

**Note :** variable names are `case sensitive` take care about that .

Comment: nothing happens. If you have a better way of writhing it you coud put me through thanks

Comment: I have . I am trying to get user_id with session so that a user can only like once. but when I click the like button nothing happens on screen or database

Comment: how do you know  ? @olar19

Comment: I just downloaded chrome back. so I checked there

Comment: put the this code inside the js function  alert('function called'); return false; and make sure that function calling or not . @King